# How to determine function have param or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i determine if function have param or not

Like

```
function Foo(bar){}
```

And

```
function Foo(){}
```

I tried to use Foo.arguments but always return null at both

How can i know when function have param or know param length?

Comment: use Foo.length to access function param len

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the number of parameters a function has via `.length`. For example,

```js
function Foo(bar){}
console.log(Foo.length); // 1
```

and

```js
function Foo(){}
console.log(Foo.length); // 0
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, that help me alots